# How do I refine Binding<MyStruct?> to Binding<MyStruct>

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hey say I have a `MainView`, that requires Binding

```
struct MainView : View {
    @Binding var myStruct : MyStruct
}
```

And I want to call this from another view, which stores `@State myStruct : MyStruct?`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myStruct : MyStruct?
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            if (self.myStruct != nil) {
                MainView(myStruct: self.$myStruct)
            } else {
                Text("Loading...")
            }
```

My intent is to fetch `MyStruct`, and conditionally load `MainView`.

However, I am not able to coerce `Binding<MyStruct?>` to `Binding<MyStruct>`

How would I go about doing that?

(May be making a noobie mistake, please bear with me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as follows

```
    return VStack {
        if self.myStruct != nil {
            MainView(myStruct: Binding(self.$myStruct)!)
        } else {
            Text("Loading...")
        }
    }
```